# How can i get the Click Target?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, textfield

i'm Dongju and Study extjs4.

I wanna return Click target's variable.

When I click the Ext.Img, I wanna get the Image's config. (e.g. x, y, Image, and so on)

How to get right Information?

this is my code

```
var paddleItem = {
xtype : 'image',
src : "lib/Image/Paddle.png",
x : 0,
y : 0,
draggable : true,
index : 0,
id : 'paddleItem',
name : 'Paddle',
width : 100,
height : 100,
listeners : {
    click : {
        element : 'el',
        fn : function(e,t,eOpts) {
            alert(t.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

};

w

Comment: Your question title is very different from what you're describing in the question itself. Which one is it? What exactly do you want?

Comment: And also, please remove extjs// from your title (again)...

Comment: @sha Is it OK sha? Sorry, i didn't know what is my fault.  And different title is my mistake. Sorry sha, and Thanks for your help. You give me a lot help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe at the point your click function is executed 't' will be the target of the click event and of type HTMLElement (According to the ExtJS API).

To get the x/y from that, you can probably use something like offsetWidth/Height if you need the position of the HTML element containing the Ext image on the page.

Alternatively, if you need properties of the var paddleItem in the click function, could you not use something like this:

```
var myPaddleImage = Ext.getCmp('paddleItem');
```

That way you'd have a reference to the Component, rather than the HTML element and could call methods on it directly.

Comment: Thank you there!(douga? Is it right?) Anyway, i'll try it tommorow. In korea is 11:30 PM so i go sleeop now : )